# substituting a dot (.) with a space (" ") awk, sed or grep

Tags: regex, sed, awk, grep

I need to go through tcpdump files which have IP addresses followed by their source or destination port in this way: `192.168.1.0.80` to this one: `192.168.1.0 80`.

How can I do this using awk, sed or grep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` :

```
tcpdump -v -n |
sed -r 's@([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,5})@\1 \2@g'
```

### EXPLANATION

- `-r` switch stands for *extented regex* (I use it to avoid parentheses backslash)
- `s@@@` is a substitution *skeleton*, the delimiter can be anything we want, not only `s///`. s/before/after/
- `(` group and capture to \1 (to \N)
- `[0-9]{1,3}` any character of: '0' to '9' (between 1 and 3 times (matching the most amount possible))
- `\.` a literal '.'
- `)` end of a capture
- `\1` and `\2` are the captured stuff
- `g` modifier stands for *all occurences*

Comment: wow it works smoothly... thank you very much, could you please explain the sinthaxis of the regexp for modifying it and applying it to further uses?